# Url only responds with the site open

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I need to scrape the information on this page
[website](https://www.agmgranite.com/inventory/hill-country-spicewood/?f=reset).

In the developer tools I found this [link](https://www.agmgranite.com/paginate.php?page=1&lid=3&f=reset&invp=) with the answers I need.

The problem is that the link with the answers only opens if the site is previously open.

How can I scrape these responses if I need the site open?

code:

```
import scrapy


class AaidSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'agm'
    starts_urls = [

        'https://www.agmgranite.com/paginate.php?page=1&lid=3&f=reset&invp='
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.body)
```

reponse:

> []

Comment: Just visit the first link first, then the second. They don't both need to be open at the same time.

Comment: what function to use for this? do you have any example?

Answer (score 1):

The second page needs to carry the cookie returned by the first page to get the data correctly. Here is an example.

```
from simplified_scrapy.spider import Spider, SimplifiedDoc
from simplified_html.request_render import RequestRender

class ToscrapeSpider(Spider):
  name = 'agmgranite.com'
  allowed_domains = ['www.agmgranite.com']
  start_urls = ['https://www.agmgranite.com/paginate.php?page=1&lid=3&f=reset&invp=']
  refresh_urls = True # For debug. If efresh_urls = True, start_urls will be crawled again.

  def extract(self, url, html, models, modelNames):
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
    print (doc.html)
    return True

  req = RequestRender({ 'executablePath': '/Applications/chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'})
  # If you need to log in to get the data you want, please rewrite this method
  def login(self):
    self.req.getCookies('https://www.agmgranite.com/inventory/hill-country-spicewood/?f=reset', self._callback,selectorOrFunctionOrTimeout='//div[@class="inv_of"]') # To get csrf_token
    return True
  def _callback(self,cookie,url,data):
    if cookie:
      self.setCookie(url,cookie)
    else:
      self.logged_in = False # If the login is not successful, try again next time

from simplified_scrapy.simplified_main import SimplifiedMain
SimplifiedMain.startThread(ToscrapeSpider())
```

Here are more examples of simplified-scrapy [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/spider_examples)

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work, have the first url refer the url with data.

```
import scrapy


class spicewood(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "spicewood"

    data_url= "https://www.agmgranite.com/initial_load.php?lid=3&f=reset&invp="

    def start_requests(self):
        urls=[
            "https://www.agmgranite.com/inventory/hill-country-spicewood/?f=reset"
            ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.second_page)


    def second_page(self):
        data_url = self.data_url
        yield scrapy.Request(url=data_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'newspicewood-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Comment: works well with https://www.agmgranite.com/paginate.php?page=1&lid=3&f=reset&invp=

but i need with
https://www.agmgranite.com/paginate.php?page=1&lid=3&f=reset&invp=

because I need to do pagination

Comment: Yes, you will have to change the 'data_url' to be dynamic